# How to check for the existence of key in a nested struct

Tags: go, struct, properties

I have the following struct

```
   type GiphyJson struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
        Data []struct {
            Images struct {
                Fixed_height struct {
                    Url string `json:"url"`
                } `json:"fixed_height"`
            } `json:"images"`
        } `json:"data"`
    }
```

and I need to access `Data[x].Images.Fixed_height.Url`. Ideally I'd like to be able to check for the existence of each of the Properties 'Data, Images, ,Fixed_height' before accessing Url to ensure I don't have a nil pointer exceptions. Since I'm fairly new to the language I was curious what the idiomatic way of doing this would be.

The following is how i'm using the struct.

```
var err error
var giphyJson GiphyJson
keyword = url.QueryEscape(keyword)
resp, err := http.Get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + keyword + "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=100")
if err != nil {
    err = errors.New("An error occured trying to contact giphy")
    return "", err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &giphyJson)
```

Comment: The answer depends solely on the type you unmarshal your JSON into. E.g. if you struct contains no pointers than there can be no nil pointer exception. Please show code.

Comment: @Volker isn't that the structs definition there? It has no pointers... to the OP, the only thing you really need to check is that `lenght(Data) > x`

Comment: In the struct above you would check that len(data) > 0; Images, Fixed_height, and Url will always have values (even if they don't exist in the JSON they will be initialized to their zero value in the struct).

Comment: Sorry I'm coming from the javascript world where everything needs to be checked against ie to the keys existed and do they match the type.

Comment: @AustinDavis that's really just static vs dynamic typing. One works really well, the other attempts to make things easier for developers while actually adding no value and inadvertently conditioning them to write egregiously shitty code :D

Comment: so just to confirm if for some reason the giphy api decides to send down some partial JSON like Data[x].Images but none of the elements in the array have the property "fixed_height" the json.Unmarshal method will not add them to the struct?

Comment: No, the struct will have `fixed_height` which will have a string `Url` and that string will be empty. Everything will be there, nothing will be null, they will have default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only required check (based on the definition of that struct) is that `len(Data) > x`. Beyond that, everything is a value type so there is no risk of a nil reference panic happening.

```
if len(Data) > x {
    // access
    fmt.Println(Data[x].Images.Fixed_height.Url)
} else {
   // do other stuff you to mitigate unexpected input
}
```